Matplotlib and Pandas: why plots don't show in a 2 x 2 subplots space
I'm having an hard time understanding what's the difference between creating a graph with matplotlib and pandas, and meanwhile I'm working on ISLP, chapter 2 exercises. I looked estensively online and it seems to me that everybody uses some sort of mixed method with matplotlib and pandas.
There is an answer elsewhere by which i understand that matplotlib uses plt.method() and pandas uses df.method()...?
Also i don't get why sometime to create a graph I need fig, ax = subplot and other times I don't
I'm confused and I'd like to grasp the difference in code writing between the two methods, and I'd like you to use my code to explain.
AIM : creating a 2  x 2 subplots space, with 4 different histograms from 4 different columns of the same pandas dataframe
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2) # creating a  2x2 figure with matplotlib

import pandas as pd
# using pandas indexing to tell where to insert graph, meanwhile using plt.hist from matplotlib for the graph (??)

axes[0,0].hist(college['Enroll'])   
axes[0,1].hist(college['Accept'])    
axes[1,0].hist(college['PhD'])     
axes[1,1].hist(college['Expend'])

plt.show()  # tell python to show me the plot (matplotlib method??)


Please be consistent in your response: method with pandas, method with matplotlib, or mixed.
And finally: what about seaborn? Is it easier or what?
Thanks all for the answers

The pandas plotting functions are just a wrapper for Matplotib plotting functions (using the default backend at least), and the same goes for seaborn, hence the ability to mix the two. Pandas plotting tries to make inferences about the data being plot based on the contents of the data frame (and has certain stylistic defaults), whereas with Matplotlib alone you'll need to be explicit about what you want to plot. However, here are two different but equivalent options using some random data generated with:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        col: np.random.randint(50, size=100)
        for col in ["Enroll", "Accept", "PhD", "Expend"]
    },
)

Purely using pandas
# plot histogram of each column in the data frame as a subplot
# with a 2x2 layout
ax = df.plot(kind="hist", subplots=True, layout=(2, 2))


Purely using Matplotlib
I'll try and get the same colours as the default Pandas ones above
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# generate 2x2 array of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

colours = ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"]

for ax, name, colour in zip(axs.flat, df.columns, colours):
    # plot histogram of each column
    ax.hist(df[name], color=colour, label=name)
    ax.legend()


Explicit indexing
If you were wanting to only use certain columns and explicitly place them in certain subplots by index, then you can do what you suggest in the question:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# first index indexes over rows and second over columns 
axs[0, 0].hist(df["Enroll"], color="C0", label="Enroll")
axs[0, 0].legend()
axs[0, 1].hist(df["Accept"], color="C1", label="Accept")
axs[0, 1].legend()
axs[1, 0].hist(df["PhD"], color="C2", label="PhD")
axs[1, 0].legend()
axs[1, 1].hist(df["Expend"], color="C3", label="Expend")
axs[1, 1].legend()

Mixed
Or, as an example of mixing things, you might want to create the axes directly using Matplotlib to have more control over how the grid looks with the various subplots arguments, but then use pandas to work out how to plot the data:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    2,
    2,
    layout="constrained",
    height_ratios=[1, 2],
    width_ratios=[3, 5],
)

# pass the axes you have created to the DataFrame plotting function
ax = df.plot(kind="hist", subplots=True, ax=axs)


Explicit indexing
As in the Matplotlib-only example, you could explicitly place a plot into each subplot with:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# pass the axes you have created to the DataFrame plotting function
ax = df["Enroll"].plot(kind="hist", ax=axs[0, 0], color="C0")
ax = df["Accept"].plot(kind="hist", ax=axs[0, 1], color="C1")
ax = df["PhD"].plot(kind="hist", ax=axs[1, 0], color="C2")
ax = df["Expend"].plot(kind="hist", ax=axs[1, 1], color="C3")

noting that the colour has to be supplied in this case otherwise all plots will have the same default colour, although the subplots argument is no longer needed.

Thanks, your response was thorough and now I understand where I was stuck

I've now also added an example of a mixture of Matplotlib and pandas.

Thanks alot, but i wonder if you could make something with indexing [row,column] the subplots since you are using for loops, therefore assuming that all the columns of a dataframe will be used but, in fact, most of the time people, use just a subset of the variables in a df, and may want to add some specific characteristics on a specific plot.

I've updated to show examples with explicit indexing too.

@Pitkin awesome response. I can't upvote.
